# How does SETH implies ETH?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I know that ETH states that 3-SAT is not solvable in $2^{o(n)}$ time, the best known bound for 3-SAT is around $O(2^{.38n})$. Whereas, SETH states that there is no universal $\delta$ such that for every positive integer $k$, a $k$-SAT problem is solvable in $O(2^{\delta n})$ time.

It is not clear to me that how does SETH is stronger, and SETH implies ETH.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The more usual (and slightly stronger) formulation of the exponential time hypothesis is that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that solving 3SAT requires time $\Omega(2^{\epsilon n})$ (see, for example, [Abboud, Backurs and Williams](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.07053.pdf)), where $n$ is the number of variables.

The strong exponential time hypothesis states that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $k\ge3$ such that solving $k$SAT requires time $\Omega(2^{(1-\epsilon)n})$ (again, see the paper mentioned above).

Showing that SETH implies ETH isn't trivial. The idea is to show that $k$SAT reduces to sparse $k$SAT, which is $k$SAT restricted to instances with $O(n)$ clauses. Such instances can be coded as 3SAT instances with $O(n)$ variables. Therefore if we can solve 3SAT in time $O(2^{\gamma n})$ for every $\gamma>0$, then we can also solve $k$SAT in time $O(2^{\gamma n})$ for every $\gamma>0$. For the details, consult [Impagliazzo, Paturi and Zane, Which problems Have strongly exponential Complexity?](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002200000191774X/pdf?md5=dc03cf0d053a9fdab68b769ab65c28fd&pid=1-s2.0-S002200000191774X-main.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I know this is somewhat unrelated, but do you know what the status of the reverse implication (that is ETH implies SETH) is?

Comment: I don’t think it’s known.

Comment: "Such instances can be coded as 3SAT instances with $O(n)$ variables." Not really accurate. The number of variables for 3SAT depends on the value of $k$ from the kSAT you reduced, not on the number of clauses/variables.

Comment: The correct details can be found in the linked paper.